# Winsows Service failed to start

Tags: windows, windows-services

I have a problem with starting my Windows Service. It's configured to start automatically and it usually does start. On sometimes it doesn't, especially on Windows 8.

The windows log contains following error:

> The XYZ service failed to start due to the following error:  The
>   service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely
>   fashion. A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for
>   the XYZ service to connect.

This is a .NET 2.0 service.

The standard cause of the problem is OnStart method that perform long synchronous operation. This is not an issue this time. In fact, I've placed a file logger in the beginning of the OnStart method and it looks like it's not invoked at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was cause by two issues:

- the executable file (exe) was signed digitally;
- there were Internet connection problems and accruing IP took a long time;

The two combined caused the service start process to timeout due to too long certificate validation.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use this on native c win32 services, and searched if .NET has something similar. Sorry if i'm wrong.

In your OnStart, use the `RequestAdditionalTime` method to inform the service control manager that the operation will require more time to complete. Documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.requestadditionaltime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, that would work in most cases. But in my case the actual OnStart() method was not even called. Validation of the certificate is performed by the OS (but includes in the service timeout). Seems like a OS bug to me :)

Comment: @andrew.fox, sorry, i have seen now your previous answer. Probably this is not allowed in your systems, but [this MS Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc756342%28WS.10%29.aspx) can help.